# How do I prevent my flex-items from overflowing in mobile-view (min-width: 0 not working!)?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I think I have a case where my flex item is shrinking past its content size. This is how the overflow looks like on mobile:

[image]

Whats overflowing is basically the text for the social media site wrapped in a div.

Here is my code:

```css
/* SOCIAL STATS */
.box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px rgb(160, 158, 158) solid;
}
.svg {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
.svg-div {
  background-color: #7279C2; 
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 150px; 
} 
.svg-path {
  fill: white;
}
.details {
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 150px; 
}
.details > * {
  line-height: 0;
}
/* NEW MEMBERS */ 
/* RECENT ACTIVITY */
.new-members, 
.recent-activity {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.member {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.member-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<section class="social-stats">
  <h2>Social Stats</h2> 

  <div class="box-container">

    <div class="box">

      <div class="svg-div">  
        <svg class="svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
          <path class="svg-path" fill="red" d="M32,3.1c-1.2,0.5-2.4,0.9-3.8,1c1.4-0.8,2.4-2.1,2.9-3.6c-1.3,0.8-2.7,1.3-4.2,1.6C25.8,0.8,24,0,22.2,0
          c-3.6,0-6.6,2.9-6.6,6.6c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.5C10.3,7.8,5.5,5.2,2.2,1.2c-0.6,1-0.9,2.1-0.9,3.3c0,2.3,1.2,4.3,2.9,5.5
          c-1.1,0-2.1-0.3-3-0.8c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,3.2,2.3,5.8,5.3,6.4c-0.6,0.1-1.1,0.2-1.7,0.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.2-0.1
          c0.8,2.6,3.3,4.5,6.1,4.6c-2.2,1.8-5.1,2.8-8.2,2.8c-0.5,0-1.1,0-1.6-0.1c2.9,1.9,6.4,3,10.1,3c12.1,0,18.7-10,18.7-18.7
          c0-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.8C30,5.6,31.1,4.4,32,3.1z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="details">
        <p>Twitter</p>
        <h1>10345</h1>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box">

      <div class="svg-div">
        <svg class="svg" enable-background="new 0 0 56.693 56.693" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 56.693 56.693" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
          <path class="svg-path" fill="green" d="M40.43,21.739h-7.645v-5.014c0-1.883,1.248-2.322,2.127-2.322c0.877,0,5.395,0,5.395,0V6.125l-7.43-0.029  c-8.248,0-10.125,6.174-10.125,10.125v5.518h-4.77v8.53h4.77c0,10.947,0,24.137,0,24.137h10.033c0,0,0-13.32,0-24.137h6.77  L40.43,21.739z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="details">
        <p>Facebook</p>
        <h1>8739</h1>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box">

      <div class="svg-div">
        <svg class="svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
        viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
          <path class="svg-path" fill="blue" d="M17.7,25.7c0-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.8c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.7c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.7c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.6
          c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.5c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.6-0.4s-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4
          c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.6-0.4c-0.2,0-0.5,0-1,0c-0.7,0-1.4,0-2,0.1c-0.7,0.1-1.4,0.2-2.1,0.5c-0.7,0.2-1.3,0.5-1.9,0.9s-1,0.8-1.3,1.4
          c-0.3,0.6-0.5,1.3-0.5,2.1c0,0.9,0.2,1.7,0.7,2.3c0.5,0.7,1.1,1.2,1.8,1.6s1.5,0.7,2.3,0.9s1.6,0.3,2.4,0.3c0.8,0,1.5-0.1,2.2-0.2
          c0.7-0.2,1.3-0.4,1.9-0.8c0.6-0.3,1.1-0.8,1.4-1.4C17.5,27.2,17.7,26.5,17.7,25.7z M15.4,9.1c0-0.8-0.1-1.6-0.3-2.5
          c-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.7-0.9-2.5c-0.4-0.8-0.9-1.5-1.6-2c-0.7-0.5-1.5-0.8-2.3-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.4-2.8,1.3c-0.7,0.9-1,1.9-1,3.2
          c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.2,1.9c0.1,0.7,0.4,1.3,0.7,2c0.3,0.7,0.7,1.3,1.1,1.8c0.4,0.5,0.9,1,1.5,1.3c0.6,0.3,1.2,0.5,1.9,0.5
          c1.2,0,2.1-0.4,2.7-1.2C15.1,11.4,15.4,10.4,15.4,9.1z M12.9,0h8.4l-2.6,1.5h-2.6c0.9,0.6,1.6,1.4,2.1,2.4s0.8,2.1,0.8,3.2
          c0,0.9-0.1,1.8-0.4,2.5c-0.3,0.7-0.7,1.3-1.1,1.8c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.2c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-1.1,1.2c-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.4,1.3
          c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.6,1.1,0.9c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.7,1.2,1.1c0.4,0.4,0.8,0.8,1.1,1.3
          c0.3,0.5,0.6,1,0.8,1.6c0.2,0.6,0.3,1.3,0.3,2c0,2.1-0.9,3.9-2.7,5.4c-1.9,1.7-4.6,2.5-8.1,2.5c-0.8,0-1.5-0.1-2.3-0.2
          c-0.8-0.1-1.6-0.3-2.3-0.6c-0.8-0.3-1.5-0.7-2.1-1.1c-0.6-0.4-1.1-1-1.5-1.7C1,27.6,0.8,26.9,0.8,26c0-0.8,0.2-1.6,0.7-2.6
          c0.4-0.8,1-1.5,1.8-2.1c0.8-0.6,1.8-1.1,2.8-1.4c1-0.3,2-0.5,3-0.7c0.9-0.1,1.9-0.2,2.9-0.3c-0.8-1.1-1.2-2-1.2-2.9
          c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5c0-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4c-0.5,0.1-1,0.1-1.3,0.1
          c-1.9,0-3.5-0.6-4.9-1.9c-1.4-1.3-2-2.8-2-4.7c0-1.8,0.6-3.4,1.8-4.8C6,1.7,7.5,0.8,9.3,0.4C10.5,0.1,11.7,0,12.9,0z M32.8,4.9v2.5
          h-4.9v4.9h-2.5V7.4h-4.9V4.9h4.9V0h2.5v4.9H32.8z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="details">
        <p>Google</p>
        <h1>2530</h1>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

I'm trying to achieve this:
[image: Desired Look]

I know that a flex item cannot be smaller than the size of its content along the main axis. I checked out the stackoverflow post on this one. However I tried implementing the advice and it still didn't work.

Can anyone offer suggestions on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have given svg-div a height and width according to viewport.  see i have write `width: 7vw; height: 7vw;` to make the svg round shape at all screen size.Later     `font-size: 2.5vw; line-height: 3vw;` in .details is used for make font responsive and stop overflow. Lastly .svg class I have added `width: 3vw;` to make the icon center of the background svg. VW will help you to maintain the layout for all screen size.

```css
/* SOCIAL STATS */

.box-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 25%;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #F9F9F9;
  border: 1px rgb(160, 158, 158) solid;
}

.svg {
  display: block;
  width: 3vw;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}

.svg-div {
  background-color: #7279C2;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 10px;
  width: 7vw;
  height: 7vw;
  max-width: 150px;
}

.svg-path {
  fill: white;
}

.details {
  width: 25%;
  max-width: 150px;
  font-size: 2.5vw;
  line-height: 3vw;
}

.details>* {
  line-height: 0;
}


/* NEW MEMBERS */


/* RECENT ACTIVITY */

.new-members,
.recent-activity {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.member {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.member-image {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 15%;
  max-width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<section class="social-stats">
  <h2>Social Stats</h2>

  <div class="box-container">

    <div class="box">

      <div class="svg-div">
        <svg class="svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
          <path class="svg-path" fill="red" d="M32,3.1c-1.2,0.5-2.4,0.9-3.8,1c1.4-0.8,2.4-2.1,2.9-3.6c-1.3,0.8-2.7,1.3-4.2,1.6C25.8,0.8,24,0,22.2,0
          c-3.6,0-6.6,2.9-6.6,6.6c0,0.5,0.1,1,0.2,1.5C10.3,7.8,5.5,5.2,2.2,1.2c-0.6,1-0.9,2.1-0.9,3.3c0,2.3,1.2,4.3,2.9,5.5
          c-1.1,0-2.1-0.3-3-0.8c0,0,0,0.1,0,0.1c0,3.2,2.3,5.8,5.3,6.4c-0.6,0.1-1.1,0.2-1.7,0.2c-0.4,0-0.8,0-1.2-0.1
          c0.8,2.6,3.3,4.5,6.1,4.6c-2.2,1.8-5.1,2.8-8.2,2.8c-0.5,0-1.1,0-1.6-0.1c2.9,1.9,6.4,3,10.1,3c12.1,0,18.7-10,18.7-18.7
          c0-0.3,0-0.6,0-0.8C30,5.6,31.1,4.4,32,3.1z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="details">
        <p>Twitter</p>
        <h1>10345</h1>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box">

      <div class="svg-div">
        <svg class="svg" enable-background="new 0 0 56.693 56.693" id="Layer_1" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 56.693 56.693" xml:space="preserve" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"> 
          <path class="svg-path" fill="green" d="M40.43,21.739h-7.645v-5.014c0-1.883,1.248-2.322,2.127-2.322c0.877,0,5.395,0,5.395,0V6.125l-7.43-0.029  c-8.248,0-10.125,6.174-10.125,10.125v5.518h-4.77v8.53h4.77c0,10.947,0,24.137,0,24.137h10.033c0,0,0-13.32,0-24.137h6.77  L40.43,21.739z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="details">
        <p>Facebook</p>
        <h1>8739</h1>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="box">

      <div class="svg-div">
        <svg class="svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 32 32" style="enable-background:new 0 0 32 32;" xml:space="preserve">
          <path class="svg-path" fill="blue" d="M17.7,25.7c0-0.3,0-0.5-0.1-0.8c-0.1-0.2-0.1-0.5-0.2-0.7c-0.1-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.3-0.7c-0.2-0.2-0.3-0.4-0.4-0.6
          c-0.1-0.2-0.3-0.3-0.5-0.6c-0.2-0.2-0.4-0.4-0.5-0.5c-0.1-0.1-0.3-0.3-0.6-0.5c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.6-0.4s-0.3-0.2-0.6-0.4
          c-0.3-0.2-0.5-0.4-0.6-0.4c-0.2,0-0.5,0-1,0c-0.7,0-1.4,0-2,0.1c-0.7,0.1-1.4,0.2-2.1,0.5c-0.7,0.2-1.3,0.5-1.9,0.9s-1,0.8-1.3,1.4
          c-0.3,0.6-0.5,1.3-0.5,2.1c0,0.9,0.2,1.7,0.7,2.3c0.5,0.7,1.1,1.2,1.8,1.6s1.5,0.7,2.3,0.9s1.6,0.3,2.4,0.3c0.8,0,1.5-0.1,2.2-0.2
          c0.7-0.2,1.3-0.4,1.9-0.8c0.6-0.3,1.1-0.8,1.4-1.4C17.5,27.2,17.7,26.5,17.7,25.7z M15.4,9.1c0-0.8-0.1-1.6-0.3-2.5
          c-0.2-0.9-0.5-1.7-0.9-2.5c-0.4-0.8-0.9-1.5-1.6-2c-0.7-0.5-1.5-0.8-2.3-0.8c-1.2,0-2.1,0.4-2.8,1.3c-0.7,0.9-1,1.9-1,3.2
          c0,0.6,0.1,1.2,0.2,1.9c0.1,0.7,0.4,1.3,0.7,2c0.3,0.7,0.7,1.3,1.1,1.8c0.4,0.5,0.9,1,1.5,1.3c0.6,0.3,1.2,0.5,1.9,0.5
          c1.2,0,2.1-0.4,2.7-1.2C15.1,11.4,15.4,10.4,15.4,9.1z M12.9,0h8.4l-2.6,1.5h-2.6c0.9,0.6,1.6,1.4,2.1,2.4s0.8,2.1,0.8,3.2
          c0,0.9-0.1,1.8-0.4,2.5c-0.3,0.7-0.7,1.3-1.1,1.8c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.9-1.3,1.2c-0.4,0.4-0.8,0.8-1.1,1.2c-0.3,0.4-0.4,0.8-0.4,1.3
          c0,0.3,0.1,0.7,0.3,1c0.2,0.3,0.5,0.6,0.8,0.9c0.3,0.3,0.7,0.6,1.1,0.9c0.4,0.3,0.8,0.7,1.2,1.1c0.4,0.4,0.8,0.8,1.1,1.3
          c0.3,0.5,0.6,1,0.8,1.6c0.2,0.6,0.3,1.3,0.3,2c0,2.1-0.9,3.9-2.7,5.4c-1.9,1.7-4.6,2.5-8.1,2.5c-0.8,0-1.5-0.1-2.3-0.2
          c-0.8-0.1-1.6-0.3-2.3-0.6c-0.8-0.3-1.5-0.7-2.1-1.1c-0.6-0.4-1.1-1-1.5-1.7C1,27.6,0.8,26.9,0.8,26c0-0.8,0.2-1.6,0.7-2.6
          c0.4-0.8,1-1.5,1.8-2.1c0.8-0.6,1.8-1.1,2.8-1.4c1-0.3,2-0.5,3-0.7c0.9-0.1,1.9-0.2,2.9-0.3c-0.8-1.1-1.2-2-1.2-2.9
          c0-0.2,0-0.3,0-0.5c0-0.1,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4c0-0.1,0.1-0.2,0.2-0.4c0.1-0.2,0.1-0.3,0.1-0.4c-0.5,0.1-1,0.1-1.3,0.1
          c-1.9,0-3.5-0.6-4.9-1.9c-1.4-1.3-2-2.8-2-4.7c0-1.8,0.6-3.4,1.8-4.8C6,1.7,7.5,0.8,9.3,0.4C10.5,0.1,11.7,0,12.9,0z M32.8,4.9v2.5
          h-4.9v4.9h-2.5V7.4h-4.9V4.9h4.9V0h2.5v4.9H32.8z"/>
        </svg>
      </div>

      <div class="details">
        <p>Google</p>
        <h1>2530</h1>
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Could you explain the logic behind what you did?

Comment: I have update the code with explanation. please check it out @AmandeepPasricha

Answer (score 0):

You have given a `width:25%` to your class `.detail`. Remove it or make it to `width:100%` and it won't overflow.

For increasing the spaces between the boxes, you can give `margin-right` to `.box`

Comment: Hey thank you for the answer. If I make the details div width 100%, wouldn’t it overtake the icon next to it? What’s the reason for removing the percentage value of on details, because wouldn’t I want to be a certain size of the box div?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't defined any font size, the text is rendered at the browser's default size: 16px for the paragraph and 24px for the headings.

With fixed sizes like this, text will overflow its container when the screen size gets too small.

Try a more responsive font size. Add this to your code:

```
.details {
   font-size: 3vw;
}
```

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/1v3bpw8L/)